# Computing the distance matrix from an adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, network

How do I do this?

I know how to compute each matrix from a given graph but don't know how to get from one to the other and what the link between the two matrices are.

PS: for graphs that are undirected, connected and simple

Comment: You need to exponentiate the adjacency matrix to a high enough power in the [min-plus algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_semiring#min-plus_algebra). This is, instead of adding you take minimum and instead of multiplying you take a sum. This computation is actually the same as what you do what you 'compute it directly from the graph'.